# Ruby On Rails getting the error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm somewhat new to ruby on rails and i'm working on nesting models for a web app i'm working on which will have goals which have steps assigned to them.

I'm working on creating a form nested with nested goals and steps but i am getting the error

"syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input"

```
    <% form_for @goal do |goal_form| %>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Goal, 'Goal:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_field :Goal %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Description, 'Description:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_area :Description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Date, 'Date:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :Date %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :DueDate, 'DueDate:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :DueDate %>
  </div>

  <!-- Here we call fields_for on the project_form builder instance.
       The block is called for each member of the tasks collection. -->
  <% goal_form.fields_for :steps do |step_form| %>
      <p>
        <div class="field">
          <%= step_form.label :requirement %><br>
          <%= step_form.text_field :requirement %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <%= step_form.label :completionTime %><br>
          <%= step_form.number_field :completionTime %>
        </div>

        <% unless step_form.object.new_record? %>
          <div>
            <%= step_form.label :_delete, 'Remove:' %>
            <%= step_form.check_box :_delete %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </p>

  <% end %>
<% end %>

<div class="actions">
    <%= goal_form.submit %>
</div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added extra `<% end %>` and your form should be `<%= form ..... %>` not `<% form .... %>`

Try to replace your above code with this:

```
<%= form_for @goal do |goal_form| %>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Goal, 'Goal:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_field :Goal %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Description, 'Description:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_area :Description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Date, 'Date:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :Date %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :DueDate, 'DueDate:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :DueDate %>
  </div>

  <!-- Here we call fields_for on the project_form builder instance.
       The block is called for each member of the tasks collection. -->
  <% goal_form.fields_for :steps do |step_form| %>
    <p>
    <div class="field">
      <%= step_form.label :requirement %><br>
      <%= step_form.text_field :requirement %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= step_form.label :completionTime %><br>
      <%= step_form.number_field :completionTime %>
    </div>

    <% unless step_form.object.new_record? %>
      <div>
        <%= step_form.label :_delete, 'Remove:' %>
        <%= step_form.check_box :_delete %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </p>

  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= goal_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @goal do |goal_form| %>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Goal, 'Goal:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_field :Goal %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Description, 'Description:' %>
    <%= goal_form.text_area :Description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :Date, 'Date:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :Date %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= goal_form.label :DueDate, 'DueDate:' %>
    <%= goal_form.date_select :DueDate %>
  </div>

  <!-- Here we call fields_for on the project_form builder instance.
       The block is called for each member of the tasks collection. -->
  <% goal_form.fields_for :steps do |step_form| %>
    <p>
    <div class="field">
      <%= step_form.label :requirement %><br>
      <%= step_form.text_field :requirement %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= step_form.label :completionTime %><br>
      <%= step_form.number_field :completionTime %>
    </div>

    <% unless step_form.object.new_record? %>
      <div>
        <%= step_form.label :_delete, 'Remove:' %>
        <%= step_form.check_box :_delete %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    </p>

  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= goal_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```